# Problem when withdraw from contract in gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I could not withdraw from contract in gnosis safe. The executing wallet has enough funds to cover for gas. Details as below:

Contract interaction: 0x4059c4a0b8a2B528C4f2E101A3bB8fB169aBa4fB - network: BEP20

Full report: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/70681469-3094-4bc2-af31-774898b0b744

The last time I did was 2 weeks ago, but it was ok.

Someone has this issue before, and how to fix it?

Comment: Whats the error message?